# how implement the observer pattern in IONIC 2

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, observable

I want to implement the observer pattern in IONIC 2.

I have this service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { Events } from 'ionic-angular';

@Injectable()
export class ExampleService {
  private _events: Events;

  constructor(public http: Http, events: Events) {
    this._events = events;
  }

  doStuff() {
    this.raiseBeginDownloadData('data');
  }

  private raiseBeginDownloadData(hash: string){
    this._events.publish('begin-download', hash);
  }
}
```

And this is my controller:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, AlertController, Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { ExampleService } from '../../providers/example-service';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-exaple',
  templateUrl: 'example.html',
  providers: [ExampleService]
})

export class MyPage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, platform: Platform, public alertCtrl: AlertController, public eventSvc: ExampleService) {

  }

}
```

My question is, how can I implement the observer patter in this case?

I know that in my service I need to create method that enables to the controller subscribe/unsuscribe to this event; and in the controller, I need to create a notify method, but I don't know how make it with IONIC 2/RxJs

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Events is a publish-subscribe style event system for sending and
>   responding to application-level events across your app.

So you can emit it in your `service` and subscribe in `Component`.

```
import { Events } from 'ionic-angular';

constructor(public events: Events) {}

// first page (publish an event when a user is created)
function createUser(user) {
  console.log('User created!')
  events.publish('user:created', user, Date.now());
}

// second page (listen for the user created event)
events.subscribe('user:created', (user, time) => {
  // user and time are the same arguments passed in `events.publish(user, time)`
  console.log('Welcome', user, 'at', time);
});
```

In your case.

```
export class MyPage {

  constructor( public events: Events) { }
  this.events.subscribe('begin-download', (user, time) => {
    // user and time are the same arguments passed in `events.publish(user, time)`
    console.log('Welcome', user, 'at', time);
  });
}
```